# What the sync method is doing and what is the frequency of heartbeat tuple?

Tags: python, apache-storm

I am using Storm 0.9.3, using Python.

I'm referring to [Multilang-protocol](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Multilang-protocol.html).

Can anyone explain:

- **what the `sync()` is doing method?**
- **what is the frequency of heartbeat tuple?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storm 0.9.3 introduced multilang subprocess heartbeat. (Actually I introduced it.)

As you already know, nimbus and supervisor check worker's heartbeat and take proper action when worker didn't write its heartbeat in time.

Multilang subprocess heartbeat is doing similar thing, but it uses multilang protocol instead of ZK.

1. Before 0.9.3, sync() is only used for ShellSpout to notify subprocess's execution of next() has been finished. After 0.9.3, Storm added new meaning to sync(), "heartbeat" (means that notifying I'm OK).
2. ShellSpout doesn't send heartbeat tuple, cause normal circumstance Spout's nextTuple() is called frequently, so does subprocess's next(). ShellBolt sends heartbeat tuple to subprocess every 1 sec.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does it mean if a multilang bolt takes more than 1 second to process the one tuple, it (multilang bolt) will not be able to sync and it will be considered dead?

Comment: No, ShellBolt updates timestamp when subprocess respond sync(). And ShellBolt periodically checks timestamp, and when difference between  current timestamp and heartbeat timestamp is greater than Config.SUPERVISOR_WORKER_TIMEOUT_SECS, it will be considered unavailable.

Comment: So subprocess has to process one tuple taking less than Config.SUPERVISOR_WORKER_TIMEOUT_SECS - (some margin). Actually ShellSpout treats all subprocess's responses as heartbeat, but it didn't applied to ShellBolt. https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/497 addresses it.

Comment: can you please answer this question of mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732178/storm-error-async-loop-died/30770970?noredirect=1#comment49596649_30770970